# How can i use the unused space in my HDD and restore it back to original form ?? does Gparted tool help?

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, merge

I installed a couple of Ubuntu versions previously only to be deleted or unused leaving the allocated space they used haunted.Using a tool like GParted how can I merge all those pieces into my original HDD space which was 500GB.Below is the picture of how it looks.Help needed very badly. [image: GParted snapshot]

Comment: "Haunted"?  This word does not make sense in this context.

Comment: @psusi, I dunno, I kind of like it.  The space was once free, but now it is inhabited by the spirits of bygone operating systems...  The operating systems died a cruel and needless death, and the user must atone for his sins to cleanse the disk. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

First, delete all the old partitions that you don't want, using gparted.  Then resize the remaining partition to take up that extra space.  It's pretty point and click; **just be sure and do it from a live CD.**

---

#### Unneeded; kept for posterity

When you're done, the partition will indeed be bigger, but Ubuntu's ext4 filesystem won't know it.  To fix this, do

```
resize2fs /dev/sdaX
```

replacing `sdaX` with the proper name of your partition.  Then reboot and you should be done!

---

To make room for ChromeOS, don't resize Ubuntu to take up all of the space; leave an unallocated block for ChromeOS.  I'm not familiar with ChromeOS's install procedure, but it will probably offer to use the unallocated space.

Comment: I don't think `resize2fs` call is needed, `gparted` does that for you

Comment: I think you're right.  Although calling it won't hurt.

Comment: Well i am clearly not able to delete old partitions.By old partitions do you mean by the number they follow ? 1 being the oldest ??

Comment: You won't be able to delete them if they are mounted.  Make sure you unmount everything on `sda` before you start.  And by oldest, I mean "the ones you don't want."  If you boot into the Ubuntu you want to keep and run `mount`, it will tell you what partitions are mounted.

Comment: it says i have to manually unmount it

Comment: Right click it and choose "Unmount."  Or go into a terminal and `sudo umount <partition>`.

Comment: I guess the flag in Gparted says sda1 is on boot ..so except sda1 rest are not mounted... am i right ??  ..I have a very little knowledge regarding this.Feel free to make your opinions more comprehensive. :)

Comment: It says `/dev/sda11` is mounted on `/`.  Are you booted from a Live CD?  You cannot resize partitions while they are mounted.

Comment: Ok.So now i'll boot from my Ubuntu live CD ?

Comment: Yes, and then follow the instructions.  Please ensure you read everything I posted in the answer; I did mention a Live CD.